# How to use the ARM XML Machine Readable Architecture Specification to assemble and disassemble?

Tags: arm

ARM has released a machine readable architecture specification as described at: https://alastairreid.github.io/ARM-v8a-xml-release/

Is there already a way to use that specification to assemble and disassemble ARM code, and if yes, how to use it with a minimal example?

There are some hints at: https://alastairreid.github.io/bidirectional-assemblers/ but I could not find a working implementation.

I know I can assemble and disassemble with existing GNU tools, but using the spec would:

- always be ahead of the GNU tools as changes are made to the spec
- more likely to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Haskell implementation: https://github.com/nspin/hs-arm

I haven't tested it, but the README claims this:

```
import Harm
import Harm.Extra
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (start, words) <- elfText "../test/nix-results/test.busybox/busybox"
    forM_ (zip [start, start + 4..] words) $ \(offset, word) ->
        putStrLn $ hex offset ++ "  " ++ hex word ++ "  " ++
            case decode word of
                Nothing -> ".inst  " ++ hex word
                Just insn -> padRight 30 (showAsmCol 7 insn) ++ encodingId insn
```

Produces something like:

```
0000000000400200  d11843ff  sub    sp, sp, #0x610         SUB_64_addsub_imm
0000000000400204  7100041f  subs   wzr, w0, #0x001        SUBS_32S_addsub_imm
0000000000400208  1a9fd7e0  csinc  w0, wzr, wzr, le       CSINC_32_condsel
000000000040020c  6a00003f  ands   wzr, w1, w0            ANDS_32_log_shift
0000000000400210  a9bd7bfd  stp    r29, r30, [sp, #-48]!  STP_64_ldstpair_pre
0000000000400214  910003fd  add    x29, sp, #0x000        ADD_64_addsub_imm
0000000000400218  a90153f3  stp    r19, r20, [sp, #16]    STP_64_ldstpair_off
000000000040021c  d0000c73  adrp   r19, 0x00018e          ADRP_only_pcreladdr
0000000000400220  91358263  add    x3, x19, #0xd60        ADD_64_addsub_imm
0000000000400224  f9400064  ldr    r4, [x3]               LDR_64_ldst_pos
...
```

Comment: Downvoters, you are too fast, I've answered it less than a minute ago and am updating the example lol

Comment: @Moritz it was a semi-intentional misclick :-)